# Is there a character level requirement for Leather work and Alchemy?

Tags: world-of-warcraft-classic

For WoW Classic (blizzard server), I want to have my main character to have skinning and herbalism and create a second character which I won't play much to have Leatherwork and Alchemy.

My question is for my second character, is there a character level requirement to reach max Leatherwork and Alchemy level.  So if i don't level my second character up (character level, no profession level), can he still craft all Leatherwork and Alchemy items?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Classic WoW has a level requirement for the different levels of crafting professions you can learn.

- Apprentice (1-75) can be learned from level 1
- Journeyman (75-150) requires level 10
- Expert (150-225) requires level 20
- Artisan (225-300) requires level 35

This level requirement only applies for professions where you craft things: Tailoring, Leatherworking, Alchemy, Engineering, Blacksmithing, and Enchanting (although there is no skill level requirement to disenchant high level items).

Gathering professions have no level requirement, but they also require you to venture out into the world to places with high level enemies.

(I'm unsure about non-primary professions such as Cooking, but those don't take up one of your two "slots" so there's no downside to levelling it on your main character)